# How do you parse a JSON.NET file without a defined structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, json.net, deserialization

I'm using an API from OpenCalais that gives me a json string that contains a bunch of JSON objects. The problem is that depending on what I pass into the API the structure of the JSON string changes, which means that I can't cast the deseralization against a custom class I could make. Another problem is that the output isn't in key value form, but rather a complicated object structure. Here is an example of the output-

```
{"doc":
{"info":
{"allowDistribution":"true",
"allowSearch":"true",
"calaisRequestID":"c1cdd79a-ed89-8431-138c-50e8a37100f9",
"externalID":"17cabs901",
"id":"http://id.opencalais.com/0RCcU306*HTR05*7HlUb5A",
"docId":"http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/6188237f-a2a5-3263-95b7-ea894ba98298",
"document":"Bill Gates worked at Microsoft from 2008 to 2011. He is also married to Melinda Gates.",
"docTitle":"",
"docDate":"2012-07-26 15:51:00.885",
"externalMetadata":"",
"submitter":"ABC"}
```

So you can see there are multiples levels of objects here and there is no key value structure. What I need from this code is essentially all of the name/value info in a dictionary. Then I can sort through based on the keys to the relevant info. It would also be cool if I could somehow also grab the parent of the object value. So for example the output I want is key: allowSearch, value: true, parent: info. I have been trying to mess around with different method of deserialization, dynamic objects, and just plain parsing using functions like .Ancestor and I haven't found anything useful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)? It can dynamically parse JSON which you can then iterate through:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject rootObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

You can iterate through the children, or search for other nodes like this:

```
JToken info = rootObject.SelectToken("info");
```

Comment: And like this: JObject["doc"]["info"]["document"]

Comment: Yeah I used this method originally, but I wanted a  way of getting all of the info from the children nodes etc without knowing the names of things. Since the output changes I want a way of getting all of the info if I don't know exactly what's coming out

Comment: Oh and that method JToken info = rootObject.SelectToken("info"); returned a null token...

Comment: Sorry about the null token error. Didn't actually test it. Should probably be SelectToken("doc.info")?

Answer (score 1):

Json.NET support **LINQ to JSON** under the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace.

[The example](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to use `JObject`

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{'CPU': 'Intel','Drives': ['DVD read/writer','500 gigabyte hard drive']}");

string cpu = (string)o["CPU"];
// Intel

string firstDrive = (string)o["Drives"][0];
// DVD read/writer

IList<string> allDrives = o["Drives"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
// DVD read/writer
// 500 gigabyte hard drive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DeserializeObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject) which essentially returns a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

For example:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> myGraph = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(myJson);
```

To read stuff from the `myGraph` dictionary, you will have to cast each step of the way.

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> doc = (Dictionary<string, object>)myGraph["doc"];
Dictionary<string, object> info = (Dictionary<string, object>)doc["info"];
string externalID = (string)info["externalID"];
```

I'm sure you could genericize it a bit, but I think that should work with the json you posted.

Comment: How would that work? This line 'Dictionary<string,object> yay = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);' returns the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)